# So, "Some advice" or "some advices"? Which is correct?

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

"*Some advice*" or "*some advices*" as in "*I got some advice / advices for you*"? So, Which is correct?

In [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/advice?q=advice), "**advice**" is uncountable noun, so "*Some advice*"  is the correct one.

However, googling "*some advices*" returns 400K results and in fact many formal English articles / news use "some advices" as in this article on Yahoo News: "[Real World 101: What Every Graduate Should Know](http://news.yahoo.com/real-world-101-every-graduate-know-150028947.html)".

> Although graduating from college is a great accomplishment which should be recognized, it is not the end. In fact, it is just the beginning of a totally new phase in life which the graduates are unfamiliar with. **Below are some advices** for the new graduates that are not thought in schools.

So, I think "*some advices*" could be accepted as an alternative to "*some advice*" though it is not 100% accurate.

Comment: "Some advices" is a classical error made by someone for whom English is not their first language.  "Below are some advices for the new graduates that are not thought in schools." is clearly written by someone in this category, as "not thought in schools" is likewise not idiomatic.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the comment left by Hot Licks is exactly what I was referring to.

Comment: @HotLicks I'd say they were typos, (in the largest sense of the word, perhaps this was dictated by voice) rather than non-native speaker's errors. The "are not thought in schools" should be *taught*

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I have seen "some advices" many many times here in Stack Exchange, in most cases clearly written by non-native English speakers.  I suspect that Stack Exchange alone could account for the "popularity" of the phrase in Google, given that this is where you come to ask for advice.  You are right, though, that "thought" may simply be a typo for "taught".  (But in any case the referenced article is poorly edited.)

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm not convinced it's just a "classical error". I believe that pluralising "advice" is *very* common in Indian English, and therefore it is very possible that it is taught in India.

Comment: closely related but not a duplicate of the following: 1.  [Plural of “advice”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63799/plural-of-advice) 2. [Is “Just a friendly advice” grammatical?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103619/is-just-a-friendly-advice-grammatical)

Comment: when I google "some advices" I get c. 18,200,000 results and for "some advice" I get c. 966,000,000 implying that only 1.85% of pages use the incorrect "some advices". *However*, of this relatively insignificant number many fall into both categories (I haven't the time to sample them right now to get an estimate of the proportion) as they are either asking or instructing as to which is the correct form. Many of those that do not fall into both categories are likely to be people who's first language is not English (judging by the first page) so do not represent "correct" English.

Comment: @MD-Tech 400K results indeed for [*"some advices"*](https://www.google.it/search?q=some+advices&oq=some+advices&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.4332j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22some+advices%22&start=60) within inverted commas. The link is on page 7 of Google, so **who's** right??

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some+advice%2Csome+advices&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csome%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20advices%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This question made me think of this classic Arnie clip where he talks about *"giving the wrong advices"*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nHHky2ufDU

Comment: Would advisements be a good substitute?  As in “I think the advisements from Alice  and Bob are spot on.” I’m trying to communicate that the advice from each of them, which is different advice, is spot on.

Comment: Would advisements be a good substitute?  As in, “I think the advisements from Alice  and Bob are spot on.” I’m trying to communicate that the advice from each of them, which is different advice, is spot on.  I don’t love that sentence but prefer it to my previous versions, “I think the advice from Alice and Bob is spot on,” and an “advices...are” version!”l

Comment: @MD-Tech: The first page of results for a Google search has annoyingly been lying to us for quite a few years now. They state a number of pages with the search terms but it's just a guesstimate. They do this to save computing resources calculating it every time. But if you go to the next page, and especially if you step through all the pages to the end, the number of hits reported gets more and more realistic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As noted, ***[advice](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advice)*** is uncountable so it takes no plural form. In the following ***[extract](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/05/advise-advice/)*** from "Oxford dictionaries", however, they hint at a legal/business usage of advice as a countable noun.

***Taking and giving advice***

> - The central difference between advice and advise is that the spelling advice, with -ice at the end, is the standard English spelling for the noun, but *never* for the verb. Advice has two meanings:
> - guidance or recommendations offered to someone about the best course of action to take in a particular situation: she gave good advice about treating everyone with respect; her help surprised him, but he took her advice.
> - ***(in business and legal use)*** a formal record of a financial agreement or other transaction: **cheques and remittance advices** were raised in alphabetical order.
> - ***Advice is mainly used with the first meaning, and in this meaning it is a mass noun (that is, it has no plural).***
> - ***The business/legal meaning, however, is a count noun: it has a plural form, advices.***
>
>   - Tip 1: there are just two possible forms for the noun: advice and advices.
>   - Tip 2: when you pronounce advice, the ending rhymes with ice.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you explained *why* there are so many "mistakes". The OP is justifiably confused by the number of positive results Google produces.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: To be fair, the OP is explicitly asking for what’s correct. If your assumption is correct, the question should either be closed (because it’s either unclear  or contains two questions in one) or edited.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft   The OP is confused by the 40K results, and says: *So, I think "some advices" could be accepted as an alternative to "some advice"* based on the evidence he has before him. One could provide  an easy enough explanation for this common error, or perhaps actually draw different conclusions. The question is very clear, and the fact two questions are implied doesn't mean the post is off-topic, they are both closely related. But if we want to be nit-picking, there is only one question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Well, you cannot have both. If you think that the question implies asking for the reason of the mistake (if it is one), this should be stated explicitly in the question. If you think that the question does not ask for this, you cannot blame answers for not answering it – in fact this would make the answer digress from the actual question in my opinion.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft whom did I put the blame on? I upvoted both answers, but added they could be *improved* on, this is the SE model, providing good answers often means explaining "why".

Comment: The OED seems to say that *advices* is an obsolete form still used in India and the Caribbean. Sir Walter Scott wrote *"This good-natured and gallant young knight is somewhat drawn aside by the rash advices of his squire,"* so it could still be used as a count noun ca. 1800.

Comment: A *remittance advice* is a concrete *thing:* a piece of paper, so you can easily have several of them. Usually *advice* is an abstract noun, and abstract nouns (like *beauty, wonder*) are uncountable until they are made concrete [the girl is a beauty; the fireworks were a wonder].

Comment: '_[A]dvice_ is uncountable' and 'In the following extract from "Oxford dictionaries", however, they hint at a legal/business usage of _advice_ as a countable noun' are incompatible. '_[A]dvice_ is usually employed as the uncountable usage'.

Answer (score 5):

"Some advices" is archaic, having passed out of use about 100 years ago.  [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some+advice%2Csome+advices&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csome%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20advices%3B%2Cc0).

Likely it is true that this usage still persists in India, as parts of the English language as used there were "frozen" about that long ago.

It is not, however, considered to be modern, idiomatic usage in the US or, to my knowledge, in the British Isles, and its use would generally cause a reader to suspect that the author was not a "native English speaker".

Comment: Advices used to be considered correct, along with informations.  I read the article quoted and something seemed "off" about it.  Anyway, up vote for you.

Answer (score 4):

"Advice" is uncountable and all those "advices" you're seeing are just mistakes.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you explained *why* there are so many "mistakes". The OP is justifiably confused by the number of positive results Google produces.

Comment: COCA has many examples of *advice* being countable. So this answer in its current form is factually wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In a sentence, "I got some advice/advices for you.", it is ***absolutely wrong*** to use *advices* as *advice* is defined as a mass (abstract) noun which is *uncountable*:

> [[***Mass Noun***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/advice)] Guidance or recommendations offered with regard to prudent action:
>   'my advice is to see your doctor" ‘he should take advice from his
>   accountant’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

However, ***advices*** are being used in the English language *in a different meaning* as follows and its plural forms are also defined in some dictionaries including Oxford Online Dictionary:

> A formal notice of a financial transaction: ‘remittance advices’
>   (also  **advices**) *archaic* Information; news:
>   ‘the want of fresh advices from Europe’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/advice) states that *advices* can be used when they mean information or notice given:

> Information or notice given; intelligence; as, late advices from
>   France; commonly in the plural. In commercial language, advice usually
>   means information communicated by letter; used chiefly in reference to
>   drafts or bills of exchange; as, a letter of advice.

Conclusion: *advice* and *advices* have a different meaning and usage.

Comment: @PeterShor I put *archaic* in the middle. When they are used in reference to drafts or exchanges, the plural form can be used. You *advise* ***a letter of credit*** from foreign banks and *advice* is used in a plural form if there are more than 2 letters of credit.