# Use of 'advice'

Tags: word-choice, nouns

As 'advice' is an uncountable noun, hence should not be used as plural, but

I have a sentence here which has word 'advices' and marked as NO ERROR without any proper explanation.

1. They are awaiting **advices** from their Singapore branch.

Note: I have gone through this question but does not able understand.

[So, "Some advice" or "some advices"? Which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282047/so-some-advice-or-some-advices-which-is-correct)

Comment: ...marked as "no error" by whom? Could you please supply us with a little more context?

Comment: Sure, but i only have this info available as i don't understand it well, put it as it is given in the book. NO ERROR means here that the sentence is grammatically correct(so how the word advices can be used, while this is uncountable noun).

Comment: Have you checked the question i have mentioned in the last. There 'advices' is used to but i do not get the explanation well.

Comment: The other answers at the duplicate post you mentioned says that "_advices_ has a limited usage in finance/legal areas", but it should not be in a grammar book. Once again what book is this found in???

Answer (score 1):

These "advices" are the physical (or electronic) notifications of payment or other business transaction and can be made plural.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advice

This I fairly common usage in payroll within the United States, especially in large companies which pay electronically through direct deposit. The employee receives a stub called a payment advice indicating hours, pay, taxes, etc... while the funds are direct deposited. The individual document is an advice while a group of them are advices.

Comment: Further explanation ? More words would be good here.

Comment: That sounds very plausible to me.

Comment: @Cascabel sorry, I have added a Merriam Webster link and a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I did not DV you, but I will now provide an uptick.